# Дополнить байт нулем слева без потери младшего бита

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Приветствую! Возникла необходимость дополнить байт нулевым битом. Для корректного считывания битов мне нужно, чтобы их было 7, но, например, в знаке space или цифрах, при вызове метода `toBinaryString()` единица выводится как `110001` Мне же необходимо дополнить ее по такому правилу, чтобы было `0110001`. Пытался сдвигом вправо делать, но теряется младший бит.

Comment: А просто добавить нужное количество нулей не вариант? типа "0" + Integer.toBinaryString(a);

Comment: if (strlen(res) == 6) res = ' ' + res как-то так, все печатные символы имеют коды не меньше 0x20 и такой метод прокатит.

Comment: Владимир, спасибо, уже второй раз выручаете!) Может, сейчас тривиальные вопросы задаю, т.к. новичок, но понемногу начинаю исправляться)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String toBinaryString7(int v) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i, v >>= 1) {
        b.append(Integer.toString(v & 1));
    }
    return b.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 5;
String result = String.format("%7s", Integer.toBinaryString(num)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(result);
```

> 0000101

---

[Демо](https://ideone.com/TkQVFO)

Comment: num = -1;
Out = "11111111111111111111111111111111"

Comment: Автор ничего не говорил про числа, двоичное представление которых не помещается в 7 бит. Это не только отрицательные числа.

Comment: -1 вполне помещается в 7 бит.